# Result of map not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm looking to update an array like this :

```
// JSX in Render
<Table size="sm" responsive striped bordered hover>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr key={-1} className="defTabCra">
                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                <th>Morning</th>
                                                <th>Afternoon travaillée</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            {this.generateMonth()}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </Table>
```

My function generateMonth() :

```
generateMonth = () => {
    return MyArrayOfMomentJs.map((item,i) => { // Item is a momentJS object
        var jour = item.format("ddd");
        jour = jour.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + jour.slice(1);
        if (item.isoWeekday() > 5 || item.CheckIfholiday()) {
            return (
                <tr key={i} className="NotWorked">
                <th>{jour + ' ' + item.format("D")}</th>
                <td />
                <td />
                </tr>
            );
        }
        else {
            var rowContainer = [];
            //Morning
            if (ArrayOfBooleanForTheMorning[i] !== null) { //null means that no choices has been made
                if (ArrayOfBooleanForTheMorning[i]) {
                    rowContainer.push(
                        <td key={i}>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="true" />
                            <MaterialIcon color="green" icon="check" />
                        </td>
                    );
                }
                else rowContainer.push(
                    <td key={i}>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="false" />
                        <MaterialIcon icon="close" color="red" />
                    </td>
                );
            }
            else rowContainer.push(<td key={i}>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <MaterialIcon icon="remove" />
            </td>);

            //Afternoon
            if (ArrayOfBooleanForTheAfternoon[i] !== null) {
                if (ArrayOfBooleanForTheAfternoon[i])
                    rowContainer.push(
                        <td key={i + 31}>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="true" />
                            <MaterialIcon color="green" icon="check" />
                        </td>
                    );
                else rowContainer.push (
                    <td key={i + 31}>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="false" />
                        <MaterialIcon icon="close" color="red" />
                    </td>
                );
            }
            else rowContainer.push(<td key={i+31}> // If null
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <MaterialIcon icon="remove" />
            </td>);
            var row = [<tr key={i}><th>{jour + ' ' + item.format("D")}</th>{rowContainer}</tr>];
            return row;
        }
    }, this);
}
```

The goal is quite simple : Everytime I make a change in the ArrayOfBooleanForTheAfternoon or ArrayOfBooleanForTheMorning, I would like to re-render the component.
And now things get strange (or maybe not, you guys will tell me :p) : The function is called everytime I make a change, which is good. The map function returns an array of JSX and the content of is good aswell. However, this new array doesn't replace the actual array already rendered.

I tried to put my jsx array in a state, to put directly my funtion in the code. Nothing works.

Anyone has any idea of what is going on ?

PS: I'm using bootstrap-react for the style of the page and his layout.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong usage of key prop looks to be the likely issue.
Do you have something unique in the item object.You could use that.
Instead of

```
<td key={i}...>
```

try

```
<td key = {item.id} ...>
```

where id is the key for the unique entity in the item object.
Same for the tr tag.

Comment: item is a moment and doesn't have any id. Aswell, every component has already is own id since I don't get any error (that I had) with this

Comment: What all properties does the momentjs object have ?anything apart from id but which is unique to that object might suffice.

Comment: Or any function that can be invoked with the item object that returns a unique string

Comment: item.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') would be unique for any momentjs object.You could try using that.

Comment: <tr key={-1} className="defTabCra">
If this doesn't run in a loop it doesn't need a key.Remove it.